# How to get Math.random() to add to returned values rather than replacing them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm brand new to javascript and jquery so bear with me if there's an obvious solution to this. I have two questions:

I'm creating a random narrator generator where you can select different narrative elements to make up a plot. For this, I have several arrays but for the sake of this example, let's show two:

```
var place = ["haunted woods","abandoned mansion", "river", "hospital"];
var decade = ["20's","30's","40's","50's","60's","70's","80's","90's"];
```

and then for each array I have the following:

```
$(".placebutton").click(function() {
$(".tags").text(place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)]);
});

$(".decadebutton").click(function() {
$(".tags").text(decade[Math.floor(Math.random()*decade.length)]);
});
```

And this works just fine and all, except each time one of the buttons is clicked, it replaces whatever had been generated previously. What I was hoping it would do was add to one another, displaying right next to eachother, like:

50's | river | abandoned mansion | 20's  (and so on...)

I've tried using .append as well but it's the same thing.

The second thing I have no clue how to do is to make these elements deletable: on hover over one of those values an X icon should appear and be able to remove only that value, with all the other elements adjusting to it (without leaving any gaps where a deleted value used to be)

I really appreciate any and all help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var place = ["haunted woods","abandoned mansion", "river", "hospital"];
var decade = ["20's","30's","40's","50's","60's","70's","80's","90's"];

function addTag(name) {
  $('<li>' + name + '<a href="#">x</a></li>').appendTo(".tags");
}

$(".placebutton").click(function() {
  addTag(place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)]);
});

$(".decadebutton").click(function() {
  addTag(decade[Math.floor(Math.random()*decade.length)]);
});
$('.tags').on('click', 'a', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
.tags {
  list-style: none;
}
.tags li, .tags li:after {
  display: inline;
}
.tags li:after {
  content: "|";
}
.tags li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tags">
</ul>
<button class="placebutton">place</button>
<button class="decadebutton">decade</button>
```